# How to prove that the sum of independent Binomials with different probabilities is not Binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Say I have two biased coins with probabilities of coming up heads $p$ and $r$, where $p\ne r$.

If I toss each of the coins $n$ times, the number of heads that show up is Poisson Binomial distributed.

But how do I prove that it is not Binomial?
I tried using MGFs but the problem gets complex really fast.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's perhaps easier if you use ordinary p.g.f.s .  Do you know the unique factorization theorem for polynomials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But MGF gives you an anwser immediately. Binomial distribution's MGF is
$$(1 - p + pe^t)^n$$
But for your distribution it looks like this
$$\prod(1 - p_i + p_ie^t)^{n_i}$$
Think about this thing as you're thinking about polynomials, replace $e^t$ term with $x$
and check what happens:
$$p^n(\frac{1}{p} - 1 + x)^n$$
$$\prod p_i(\frac{1}{p_i} - 1 + x)^{n_i}$$
As you can see, it can not be the same polynomial, unless $p_i$ equals $p$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1):

If it would be binomial then it must have parameters $2n$ and $q$.

Then the expectation should be $2nq$ and variance should be $2nq(1-q)$.

That leads to $2nq=\mathbb EX=np+nr$ or equivalently: $$2q=p+r\tag1$$

And $2nq(1-q)=np(1-p)+nr(1-r)$ or equivalently: $$2q-2q^2=p-p^2+r-r^2\tag2$$

Substituting $(1)$ in $(2)$ we find:$$(p-r)^2=0$$

This contradicts that $p\neq r$ so under that condition it is excluded that we are dealing with binomial distribution.

Comment: They are tossing each coin $n$ times, so the first parameter should be $2n$, not 2.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you. I misread and thought it concerned two coins with different chance on heads that were thrown. I will delete within some minutes (and maybe will repair).

Comment: It wouldn’t take much to fix, the same proof works, except you have to consider P(X = 2n), and do a little more simplification

Comment: @MikeEarnest I repaired (and now used variance).